# Make text wrap when it meets sibling span

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically, I have two span elements: one pulled left, the second pulled right.

The one on the left is bigger, the one on the right is supposed to just show a number.

What I am trying to achieve is - while resizing the window, make the left span line break when it meets the right span and center the right span vertically when it happens (since the container div will probably gain some additional height). Any ideas?

Here is the code: http://www.jsfiddle.net/1db4trxo/5/

```css
.pricing {
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #f6c42b;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing">
  <span class="left"> Wow, there's kinda lot of text here </span>
  <span class="right"> Just a price </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do this, and you don't need floats. In fact, [floats are ignored in a flex container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers).

[**Revised Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1db4trxo/6/)

```css
.pricing {
    display: flex;                    /* establish flex container */
    justify-content: space-between;   /* align children at opposite ends */
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.left {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.right {
    white-space: nowrap;             /* prevent text from wrapping */
    align-self: center;              /* center element vertically */
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #f6c42b;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing">
  <span class="left"> Wow, there's kinda lot of text here </span>
  <span class="right"> Just a price </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [CSS table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) with browser support of IE8+.

Set the container as `display: table;` two columns inside as `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` and `text-align: right; white-space: nowrap;` on the right column.

Open the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gepd7xhr/)**, resize the result panel and see.

```css
.pricing {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.left, .right {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.right {
  color: #f6c42b;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing">
  <span class="left"> Wow, there's kinda lot of text here </span>
  <span class="right"> Just a price </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a width of both inner divs
like this

```
.left
{
    width: 75%;
}

.right
{
    width: 25%;
}
```

it's work for me.

Comment: This can possibly work, but it will not use all avilable space and probably make the span.right wrap as well, when the viewport gets smaller

Comment: you're right but if you want to use your site in small devices you should use (@media)